# DHTML module drupal 7

Tags: drupal, firefox, module, dhtml

I just used DHTML module to achieve accordion behavior with my menus. Anyway it works ok with chrome., safari and opera but in firefox it doesn't. It reloads the page.

Has anyone encountered this problem?
this [site](http://dev.ermarian.net/dhtml_menu/admin/settings/dhtml_menu) is the demo site of DHTML module developer. Test it in firefox to see if it reloads the page instead of expanding the menus in the block

Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just checked with both firefox and IE its work fine and not loading page over click.. did you verify the DHTML Menu setting under site configuration, uncheck the checkboxes under Menus without DHTML: to make accordions works.

another thing why you using DHTML module for accordion while drupal 7 already have a jquery accordion library by default.

Comment: It turns out that something was wrong with my version of firefox. Your idea about build in accordion is interesting. I guess it needs custom code to remember what page i am viewing in order to keep the accordion open for this specific submenu to stay open. Any tutorial about this?

Comment: add this code in your form and follow the div structor defined in jquery accordion demo.

`function accordion_example_form($form_state){

jquery_ui_add('ui.accordion');

    drupal_add_js('$(function() {
      $( "#accordion" ).accordion({
     });
     });', 'inline');

//follow the form code.. here

}`

or read this [thread](http://drupal.org/node/1024694)

Answer (score 0):

I always have problems with menus when I am logged in as a main  admin.

Try logout as I am also not able to replicate your problem.

Cheers,
Vishal